# Giving route controller priority in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I was following this tutorial and everything went well: http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

Except I `$scope.message` is being changed fine in `/about` and `/contact` while adding a new scope (`$scope.prodoc`) in the exact same way is not working. Instead it's displaying the mainController scope on every page.

Here are the three controllers:

```
calculatorApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $http) {
        //define the hardware data
        $scope.prodoc = 'companyb';
        $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';

    });

    calculatorApp.controller('contactController', function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.prodoc = 'companya';
        $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
    });


    // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
    calculatorApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {

        //define the hardware data
        $scope.prodoc = 'sdf';

        // create a message to display in our view
        $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
```

The body tag is in a `<body ng-controller="mainController">`

I am guessing that the `mainController` is taking priority and therefore not updating for each routed controller.

How do I force it to take the route-specific value?

EDIT:
Here's the router config:

```
calculatorApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            });
    });
```

Although I don't actually have anything to display in the template. I just need the routing for the data (`prodoc`)

Comment: Can you show the template?

Comment: And the `$routeProvider` configuration?

Comment: @IlanFrumer - Mah nishma. I added the routing. The template is negligible as I don't need the routing for any view. Only to pass the data into the main controller. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: @musically_ut added! I am trying to use the data from the contact and about controllers in the main controller based on the route. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to share the same scope variable across child scopes then you must use the dot notation rather than using a primitive value on the scope:

```
// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
calculatorApp.controller('mainController', function($scope, $http) {        
  $scope.customs = {
    prodoc : 'sdf',
    message : 'Everyone come and see how good I look!'
  };
});

calculatorApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.customs.prodoc = 'companyb';
  $scope.customs.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';        
});

calculatorApp.controller('contactController', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.customs.prodoc = 'companya';
  $scope.customs.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

---

From [Understanding-Scopes wiki](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes):

> Scope inheritance is normally straightforward, and you often don't even need to know it is happening... until you try 2-way data binding (i.e., form elements, ng-model) to a primitive (e.g., number, string, boolean) defined on the parent scope from inside the child scope. It doesn't work the way most people expect it should work. What happens is that the child scope gets its own property that hides/shadows the parent property of the same name. This is not something AngularJS is doing – this is how JavaScript prototypal inheritance works.
>
> ...
>
> This issue with primitives can be easily avoided by following the "best practice" of [**always have a '.'**](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m) in your ng-models – watch 3 minutes worth. Misko demonstrates the primitive binding issue with ng-switch.

Also see this tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DTx23w4z6Kc

Comment: TODA! This worked perfectly! The only thing that needs to be changed is to put the initial data definition in the mainController. I am suggesting the edit.

Comment: @itamar yeah that's what I mentioned :)